# Series versus dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I've just begun learning some pandas, so apologies if I'm not the best at explaining my question.

```
# creating a range of times starting from '1/1/1' going forward hourly for 100 units.
longTimeRange = pd.date_range('1/1/1', periods=31, freq='H')
# Creating a random number for each time unit as a Series
aTimeSeries = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(longTimeRange)), index=longTimeRange)

aTimeSeries.head()
```

The above code creates a series object shown below.

```
2001-01-01 00:00:00   -0.657026
2001-01-01 01:00:00   -1.244964
2001-01-01 02:00:00   -0.016981
2001-01-01 03:00:00    1.817097
2001-01-01 04:00:00   -0.419140
Freq: H, Length: 31, dtype: float64
```

My question is that the output has TWO columns. Why is it still considered a series?
Why is this not a dataframe?
If series can have more than one column, then how is that differentiated from a dataframe?
Are series and dataframes just container of holding the data in a way that it can be specifically accessed?

Comment: It's the index. Check `aTimeSeries.index`.

Comment: Then a N columns DataFrame would have N+1 "columns" in the output ;)

Comment: [refer here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pandas-series-vs-single-column-dataframe#:~:text=As%20noted%20in%20the%20table,to%20have%20an%20index%20defined)

Comment: Thank you so much! Love that explanation!

Comment: I get it now that I was confusing index with column, but that's not the case. I'm going to keep probing and check all my series to convince myself, haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is valid and shows that you're thinking critically about the structure of data in Pandas. See if the following explanations are useful to you.

**Series:**

A Pandas Series is a one-dimensional labeled array that can hold data of any type (integer, string, float, etc.). It has an index that provides labels for the data points, allowing for easy and efficient data access and manipulation.

In your example, when you create `aTimeSeries`, you are indeed creating a Series. The data you generated (random numbers) is associated with a datetime index. Each row of your output represents a single data point (number) associated with a specific timestamp. The two columns you see in the output are the index (timestamps) and the data values (random numbers).

A Series can be thought of as a single column of data, where each element is associated with a label (index). In your case, the index is the datetime, and the data is the random numbers.

**DataFrames:**

A DataFrame, on the other hand, is a two-dimensional labeled data structure with columns that can be of different types. It's similar to a table in a relational database or an Excel spreadsheet. Each column in a DataFrame is a Series. A DataFrame allows you to store and manipulate data in a structured and tabular format.

The distinction between Series and DataFrames is essentially about the dimensionality of the data:

Series: One-dimensional labeled array (single column of data).
DataFrame: Two-dimensional labeled data structure (multiple columns, each of which is a Series).

In your example, if you were to create a DataFrame, you could do so like this:

```
# Creating a DataFrame with a single column
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': aTimeSeries})
```

This would create a `DataFrame` named `df` with one column named `data`, and each row would represent a timestamp along with the associated random number.

Comment: Thank you so much for saying that! And your answer helped so much! I understand now that I was confusing index with a column. It's still one dimensional data accessed through specific indices, appreciate the clarity here, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's unambiguously a Series.

The first "*column*" is the **Index** (you could even have more levels with a MultiIndex).

What matters is the number of dimensions:

```
aTimeSeries.ndim
# 1
```

If you convert [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), the number of dimensions is now `2`:

```
df = aTimeSeries.to_frame(name='col')

df.ndim
# 2
```

You will immediately notice the column name(s) as header:

```
print(df)

                          col   # column name(s)
2001-01-01 00:00:00 -0.943661
2001-01-01 01:00:00 -0.959935
2001-01-01 02:00:00 -0.211081
...
2001-01-02 04:00:00  0.245525
2001-01-02 05:00:00 -0.285114
2001-01-02 06:00:00 -0.105460
```

For a Series, the name (if existing) is at the bottom:

```
print(aTimeSeries)
                                # no header
2001-01-01 00:00:00    0.308899
2001-01-01 01:00:00   -0.475546
2001-01-01 02:00:00    0.240019
...
2001-01-02 04:00:00    0.254641
2001-01-02 05:00:00    0.845304
2001-01-02 06:00:00   -1.636668
Freq: H, Name: col, dtype: float64  # here
```

Comment: That's so interesting! Thanks for that tip! Makes complete sense!